# How do I finish the escaped criminal quest in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Xbox 360 and the escaped criminal quest for Skyrim moved to the finished part of the quest and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Escaped criminal? You mean the redguard woman?

Comment: It is one of the companion quest

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Escaped_Criminal this one? (That is a normal radiant quest).

Comment: Yeah that's the quest that went to the finished side even though I didn't complete it

Comment: A random person could have killed your target. The talk page says some people also have had a broken quest. Don't think it is fixable on the 360 (as you don't have access to the console).

Comment: Well, I'm only one person, and have not run into that problem. So check back later if somebody knows.